# C++ : second child class is unable to inherit the properties from the parent class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

> Write a c++ program using inheritance to display the count of apples and mangoes in a basket of fruits.
>
> Make three classes fruit, apple and mango. Fruit as the base class and apple and mango as child classes.
>
> The fruit class should contain all the variables and two functions to input values and calculate the total number of fruits in the basket.
>
> The child classes apple and mango should each contain a function that prints the number of apples/mangoes in the basket

I have come up with the following code as the answer :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class fruit
{
public:
    int apples = 0, mangoes = 0;
    int total_fruits = 0;
    void input_fruits()
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of apples : ";
        cin >> apples;

        cout << "Enter the number of mangoes : ";
        cin >> mangoes;
    }

    void calculate_total()
    {
        total_fruits = apples + mangoes;
        cout << "The total fruits in the basket are : " << total_fruits << endl;
    }
};

class apple : public fruit
{
public:
    void show_apples()
    {
        cout << "The number of apples in the basket is : " << apples << endl;
    }
};

class mango : public fruit
{
public:
    void show_mangoes()
    {
        cout << "The number of mangoes in the basket is : " << mangoes << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    apple a1;
    mango m1;
    a1.input_fruits();
    a1.show_apples();
    m1.show_mangoes();
    a1.calculate_total();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output, where the mangoes count doesn't work:

[image]

When the `show_mangoes()` function is called, it is returning the previously declared value of the `mangoes` i.e. `0`. If I remove the value at declaration, the function is returning the pointer value.

I couldn't figure out the reason of why the `mango` class is not able to access the data from the `fruit` class.

But I was able to come up with two **hacky ways** of getting the output.

1. Declaring the variables in global scope:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int apples = 0, mangoes = 0;
int total_fruits = 0;

class fruit
{
public:
    void input_fruits()
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of apples : ";
        cin >> apples;

        cout << "Enter the number of mangoes : ";
        cin >> mangoes;
    }

    void calculate_total()
    {
        total_fruits = apples + mangoes;
        cout << "The total fruits in the basket are : " << total_fruits << endl;
    }
};

class apple : public fruit
{
public:
    void show_apples()
    {
        cout << "The number of apples in the basket is : " << apples << endl;
    }
};

class mango : public fruit
{
public:
    void show_mangoes()
    {
        cout << "The number of mangoes in the basket is : " << mangoes << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    apple a1;
    mango m1;
    a1.input_fruits();
    a1.show_apples();
    m1.show_mangoes();
    a1.calculate_total();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image: output for global variables]

2. Inheriting apple class instead of mango:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class fruit
{
public:
    int apples = 0, mangoes = 0;
    int total_fruits = 0;
    void input_fruits()
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of apples : ";
        cin >> apples;

        cout << "Enter the number of mangoes : ";
        cin >> mangoes;
    }

    void calculate_total()
    {
        total_fruits = apples + mangoes;
        cout << "The total fruits in the basket are : " << total_fruits << endl;
    }
};

class apple : public fruit
{
public:
    void show_apples()
    {
        cout << "The number of apples in the basket is : " << apples << endl;
    }
};

class mango : public apple
{
public:
    void show_mangoes()
    {
        cout << "The number of mangoes in the basket is : " << mangoes << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{

    mango m1;
    m1.input_fruits();
    m1.show_apples();
    m1.show_mangoes();
    m1.calculate_total();
    return 0;
}
```

Ouput :

[image: inheriting from apple class]

Can you please explain why the mango class was unable to access the variable from the parent class in the first version of the code. Any suggestions for better approach are also appreciated.

Comment: The fruit class shouldn't know about apples or mangos. What if we add bananas ? We'd have to modify fruit too. I suspect fruit should just have a count with a getter and setter but then there is no advantage to having subclasses. Unless this is a starter and the plan is to add more classes (like say "basket") then the suggested class breakdown is terrible.

Comment: Yeah, well this was the requirement shared by the prof. It was a just a practice question

Comment: These requirements seem to be stated by somebody who doesn't understand the first thing about object oriented programming.

Comment: and that is the reason he couldn't figure out the error in the first place and I had to post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When show_mangoes() function is called it is returning the previously declared value of the mangoes i.e. 0

The **problem** is that you never used `m1.input_fruits()` for `m1` while for `a1` you did use `a1.input_fruits()`. And since you never called `input_fruits` on `m1` its data member `mango` still has the value(`0`) from the **in-class initializer**.

So to solve this just call `input_fruits()` on `m1` and it will give the desired output(which is the value entered by the user), as shown below.

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/zkcsKVq7c)

```
int main()
{
    apple a1;
    mango m1;
    a1.input_fruits();
    a1.show_apples();
    
    m1.input_fruits(); //ADDED THIS which was missing before in your example 1
    m1.show_mangoes();
    a1.calculate_total();
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Anoop, I was under the impression that the variables will be updated at every child class, if called in one child class.

Comment: @Pranav That was a wrong assumption. Instead `mango` and `apple` are separate and one will not directly affect the other. You're welcome.